# cout char* is different even when declared constant

Tags: c++

I have a very simple code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string getString() {
  return "test";
}

int main(){
  const char* testString = getString().c_str();
  cout << "string 1:" << testString << endl;
  string dummy[] = {"1","2","0"};
  cout << "string 2:" << testString << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I expect the two couts will print the same output, but the output I got is

```
string 1:test
string 2:1
```

Can anyone explain why is this happening? Also, there are two things that I observed:

1) If `dummy[]` is of `int` type, then they will print the exact same strings `test` as expected.

2) If I first assign `getString()` to a string variable, then change the first line in main to `const char* testString = variable.c_str();` then they will cout the same strings as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior is undefined.

```
const char* testString = getString().c_str();
```

`getString` returns a temporary object which is destroyed when the evaluation completes. As the result. `testString` points at internals of a destroyed object, causing undefined behavior.

In practice, it may happen that the data is still at that address for some time, that's why the first `cout` gives illusion of correctness.

Comment: @Elod: Memory was allocated for the temporary; but, being temporary, it  was destroyed at the end of this line.

Answer (score 1):

You set pointer to a temporary object that will be deleted after this declaration

```
const char* testString = getString().c_str();
```

So the program has undefined behaviour.

The correct code could look like

```
const char * getString() {
  return "test";
}

int main(){
  const char* testString = getString();
//...
```

because string literals have static storage duration.

Comment: That fixes the simple example; but doesn't help when you need to return a `string`.

Comment: @Mike Seymour It is another question. You may ask it here yourself.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a low level character pointer from a string object that manages the memory for that string, the pointer is only good for as long as *that specific* object is alive.

It's more narrow than that, actually.  If you call any non-const members on the string object,  it means you can't trust any values you got from previous calls to `c_str()` to still be good--even if the object destructor has not run.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string getString() {
    return "test";
}

int main(){
    string testString = getString();
    const char * testCstring = testString.c_str();
    cout << "string 1:" << testCstring << endl;
    string dummy[] = {"1","2","0"};
    cout << "string 2:" << testCString << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

That's legal, but do not rely upon the pointer from c_str() after you have made any modifying change to the string you got it from -or- that string having been destroyed.

Also note there's no need to get a char * from a string in order to output it.  Start thinking in terms of using string objects and don't go to char * unless you have a good reason.